# Authentication Based on a String and Location

Tags: ios, authentication, geolocation, firebase, backend

I'm trying to create a social media iOS app backed by Firebase. The users don't need to register for the app, they just need to enter a "hashtag" created by someone else and be in the proximity (say 2 miles) of the creator, and they will be authenticated based on that. The hashtag won't be public unless the creator shares it with others. Authorized users should be able to upload/download/view files which other users have uploaded.

I know Firebase provides old fashioned username+password authentication, but do I need to write my own logic for this kind of authentication? Also, is this method of authentication secure? Thank you!

Comment: I cannot help much. But is the hashtag public? Is the location of the creator public? If so, anyone would be able to "login". What I mean is that the location can be spoofed.

Comment: The hashtag won't be public unless the creator shares it with others. Location spoofing is something I didn't think of. Is there a more secure way to authenticate someone, without them have to register or have an account?

Comment: I don't really know what you plan to do so it's difficult to advise - Like why do you need to authenticate clients? To keep statistics? To authorise access to their own data? What resource do you need to protect, access to some data? Or you just want to provide access to your data to people that know people you trust?

Comment: Authorized users should be able to view / upload / download files other authorized users posted under the same hashtag. So basically grants them additional rights and permissions

Comment: I still don't fully understand the model, so I won't be able to help much. Just consider that users can spoof their locations and they can get or guess hashtags so they could get authorised. I'm not sure anyway how they get the hashtag in the first place.

Comment: The creator of the hashtag can share it with others so they may join. Anyways, I felt like it's really convenient for people not have to log in/register an account.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But then why don't you do like hassle free Websites such as Mega or Wetransfer? You could use emails instead of hashtags. Your model atm is that the creator shares (by email? blueetoth? Web?) a (probably weak) "password" with others (the hashtag) and then you apply a geographical restriction (that could be spoofed). Anyone able to read this shared "password" will access the resources. I'm not sure if you need to do a strong authentication but your current model is weaker than the usual user/password, although probably less tedious for users. You could alternatively use PKCrypto